# PHP Display search result text file in external html file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to create a html form in the file index.html from where I can query a text file for a line of characters through PHP via the file searchFile.php, get the specific line and display it in said form in index.html.

My problem is that I nothing is displayed in my **Search Results** field, neither the error message or a search result.

**Update!** I've investigated my problem further and I realized that the way I'm using the `Search` button doesn't allow for any echoes to stay displayed on the page before the page is updated again and the `echo`content is removed. Still, I don't know how I should solve this issue without using two buttons, one for searching and one for getting the result of the search.

This is what I've come up with so far:

**index.html**

```
      </head>

                <body>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
           $(function() {

           // getting the search term
        var searchString = $("#search_box").val();
        // forming the searchString
        var data = 'search='+ searchString;

        //if searchString is not empty
        if(searchString) {
            // call ajax
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "searchFile.php",
                data: data,
              beforeSend: function(html) { // this happens before actual call
                    $("#results").html(''); 
                    $("#searchresults").show();
                    $(".word").html(searchString);
               },
               success: function(html){ // this happens after we get results
                    $("#results").show();
                    $("#results").append(html);
              }
            });    
        }
        return false;


});


</script>


<form name="theForm" method="post">
Name: <input type='text' onclick="ajaxFunction();" name='search' class='search_box' id='search_box'/> <br />
<input type='submit' value='Search' class="search_button" ><br />

</form>

<div id="searchresults">Result: <span id="results" class="update"></span></div>




</body>
</html>
```

**searchFile.php**

```
<?php
$search = explode(' ', $_REQUEST["search"]);

$lines = file('file-export.txt'); 
foreach($lines as $line) 
{ 
    if(strpos($line, $search[0]) !== false && strpos($line, $search[1] !== false)) { 
        echo '<div id="searchresults">' . $search . '</div>';
    }else{

    echo '<div id="searchresults">' . "No match" . '</div>';


    }
} 
?>
```

Edit: updated the button field with **action="searchFile.php"**
Edit 2: Functioning **Search** button
Edit 3: Minor changes

Comment: please post your `ajaxFunction();` and if possible how/where you handle the `POST` variables.

Comment: Added to the index.html

Comment: please check console log and display error there

Comment: I'm coding in dream weaver, which doesn't have a console or logging function? I get no errors when I test my page in my browser and I have no errors in my code.

Comment: your output field for a success does not echo anything other than `$search`.  As a debugging technique, try putting some dummy text in there to see whether it is outputting anything at all (e.g. `echo 'search result: ' . $search;`)  This way you can see whether the issue is with the search or with the output.

Comment: Tried with some dummy text and I get none of it to show up in `index.html`. So there must be something wrong with the way I'm trying to output the data then?

Comment: keep following this technique.  see if you can boil down the script to its bare minimum, until you get a result. start small, then build.  For instance, you may want to try to see if your ajax is working at all.  Try changing this field:  `url: "searchFile.php"` to call a simple php field that just echoes a Hello world or something.

Comment: I've investigated further as of your instructions and I believe the problem lies within the fact that my `searhFile.php` doesn't get activate in the first place, when I press the **Search** button.

Comment: ok sounds like you are on the right path.  the next step would be to try to get it to activate anything at all.   In other words, break everything down until you get to something that works and then slowly build it back up again.  good luck

Comment: Alright, now I'm 100% sure my button is working (check the updated code in index.html). Only getting the code to search thorugh my text file and display the result left. Any thoughts?

Comment: I read that the result of the echo in my searchFile.php will be outputed to the `data` variable in my ajax function, so I should be able to print the content of `data` in my **searchresults** div, but I'm not.

Comment: In your code:  var searchString = $("#search_box").val(); You have no element with that ID. You have an input with that class, so it should be $(".seach_box").val()

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It made no difference though.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find a search string in the block that doesn't exist

```
    var searchString = $("#search_box").val();
```

You have no block with id *search_box*, only with class *search_box*, that is *$(".search_box")* or

```
    <input type='text' onclick="ajaxFunction();" name='search' class='search_box' id='search_box'/>
```